# Create variable from string in python

Tags: python, pandas, function, dataframe, variables

I have read a lot of posts about this subject but I haven't found an answer to my problem.

Wants to write a function that allows you to create DF with different names and columns.

So I try this:

```
def createDT(name,c1,c2,c3):
    name = pd.DataFrame(columns = [c1,c2,c3])
    print(type(name))
    return name
createDT(DT,"col1","col2","col3")
```

and I receive:

```
NameError: name 'DT' is not defined
```

when I change the "name" variable to String I receives the message:

```
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
and the table below
```

Which confirms the creation of DF, but if I want to call the DT variable I get a

```
NameError: name 'DT' is not defined
```

I know I can do it this way

```
DT2 = createDT(DT,"col1","col2","col3")
```

But then I have to name the variables again and I would like to avoid that and 
I want it to be written as a function. Any ideas on how to solve it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's not that easy unfortunately:

```
def createDT(name,c1,c2,c3):
    globals()[name] = pd.DataFrame(columns = [c1,c2,c3])
    print(type(globals()[name]))
    return globals()[name]
createDT("DT","col1","col2","col3")
```

But a preferred and efficient solution would be:

```
def createDT(name,c1,c2,c3):
    return pd.DataFrame(columns = [c1,c2,c3])
createDT("col1","col2","col3")
```

Comment: Thank you so much. Could you also describe to me what was the problem and whether writing things this way is good programming practice?

Comment: @Kepasere Because when you do `name = ...` it assigns a variable called `name`, not `DT`, also may you accept it as well?

Comment: @Kepasere this is absolutely not a good practice, and it is considered an antipattern

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Added a better one

Answer (score 1):

Wouldn't simple

```
def createDT(c1,c2,c3):
    temp = pd.DataFrame(columns = [c1,c2,c3])
    print(type(temp))
    return temp

DT = createDT("col1","col2","col3")
```

work?

In Python you (almost always) don't use function parameters as return value. And you don't need to worry about copying since in Python everything is (kind of like) pointers.